# Changing the color of edges in networkX

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using [`networkX`](https://networkx.org/) to plot graphs. and I want to change the color of a graph. I followed samples on the  internet and following is my code:

```
def draw_graph():
    colors = []
    for i in range (nCount):
        for j in range (nCount):
            if ifActive(i,j,timeStep) == 1:
                colors.append("r")
                  
            else:
                colors.append("b")
                
    print ("colores = ", colors)                            
    color_map = []   
    nColor= nx.get_node_attributes(graph,'color')
    for nc in nColor:
        color_map.append(nColor[nc])
    nx.draw(graph,pos=nx.spring_layout(graph),edge_color = colors , node_color = color_map,with_labels = True )
```

but I am faced with the following error:

```
edge_color must be a color or list of one color per edge
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: how many values are in `colors`?

Comment: the count of colores are different and the value can only be green or blue @drum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is to use separated functions of networkx.
Here is a simple example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(30,0.4)

options = ['r','b']
colors = []
for i in range(len(graph.edges())):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        colors.append(options[0])
    else:
        colors.append(options[1])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph,pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph,edge_color=colors,pos=pos)
```

Example of an ER network with different edge colors:
[image: Example of an ER network with different edge colors]

**Edit:**
In your for loop you are considering two times the same edge. Try to change to the following:

```
for i in range (nCount):
    for j in range (0,i):
        if ifActive(i,j,timeStep) == 1:
            colors.append("r")
        else:
            colors.append("b")
```

Comment: thank you but yet it gives me separate nodes with the same error

Comment: Ok! Maybe i understand your problem. You are working with directed or undirected graph? Because in the list of colors you are inserting two times the color of an edge for example. In the for loop you consider the two ways of conections between i, j. Like (i,j) and (j,i).

The list of edge colors must have the same length of edges in your graph!

Comment: thank you. the problem was that I use undirected graph but set colours for directed graphs.